# How to disable text-to-speech in verify user API in Nexmo?

Tags: vonage

And so I have this code:

```
const nexmo = require("./nexmo");

const requestId = null;

module.exports = function sendVerificationCode(
  recipient
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nexmo.verify.request({
        number: recipient,
        brand: 'Verification' 
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (result.status === 0) {
            requestId = result.request_id;
        }

        return requestId;
    });
  });
};
```

This successfully returns the request ID. But what I'm concerned about is I want the API's text-to-speech mechanism to be disabled. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact nexmo support support@nexmo.com and ask them to disable TTS on Verify.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a certain type of workflow.
https://developer.vonage.com/en/verify/guides/workflows-and-events